# appgyver navigation bar image

Tags: cordova, navigationbar, steroids

I have been looking at the appggyver docs and noticed that you can only set a title bar or navigation bar image in IOS.

I may be looking at the wrong section as I am not super familiar with appgyver but I wanted to get some more clarification as to what is possible with android and IOS.

I currently have an app that requires the native header to contain an image but from reading the docs this is only supported in IOS? I would like to know if this is possible in both IOS and Android, and if not possible in Android is there a reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppGyver employee here – images on the native navigation bar are not yet available on Android. We recently [made the decision](http://blog.appgyver.com/heartbeat/steroids/android-as-a-first-class-citizen) to focus on remaking the current Android client to ensure that it's stable and the basic functionalities work flawlessly. Once that's out, we'll start on bringing all native UI features on par with iOS. So, no ETA on that yet, but we'll keep everyone updated on the progress.

Comment: Hi harsa, I tried on appgyver forum as well but never get reply I needed :( I just want to place image/icon buttons on left and right of <super-navbar>. There must be some way around to do this. Can you please guide me?

Comment: The Supersonic docs about buttons in Navigation Bar seem to be currently quite scarce. You could refer to the older Steroids.js documentation https://x.appgyver.com/categories/3-user-interface-and-design/contents/13-updating-the-navigation-bar -- Create a `new steroids.buttons.NavigationBarButton();` then insert it with 
`steroids.view.navigationBar.update({
        buttons: {
          right: [theButtonYouCreatedAbove]
        }
    });`

Comment: Still not possible almost 2 years after? I'm trying to have my logo centered on my Navigation Bar (Supersonic.) I'm putting it as a SVG `background-image` on `navigation-bar`, it works like a charm on iOS but expands and take the whole place on Android and I can't figure out how to do it properly.